# Compiling QT in windows 64 - undefined reference to

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7-x64, qmake, undefined-reference

Ok. I just installed Qt from: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads using the online installer. I have MinGW, make, gcc and g++ installed. I also added variables `QMAKESPEC` and `QTDIR` and also appended the directories in MinGW and Qt to the `PATH` variable. When running qmake and make I get a ton of errors about undefined reference to `QGraphicsScene`, `QGraphicsView`, etc.

Here's one of many:

`./debug/mox_roiwindow.o:moc_roiwindow.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV9roiwindow[vtavle for roiwindow]+0x74): undefined reference to 'QGRaphcisScene::drawForeground(QPainter*, QRectF const&)'`

The LIBS section in the makefile is:

`LIBS        =        -L'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2008/lib' -lmingw32 -lqtmaind -lQtGuid4 -lQtCored4`

The INCLUDE section is:

`INCPATH       = -I'../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2008/include/QtCore' -I'../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/msvc2008/include/QtGui'`

This appears to be correct. I tried to look up a solution via google and either found nothing or the solutions didn't seem to help. Thanks.

Comment: Is `QGRaphcisScene` a mispelling in your code?

Comment: No. Code compiles fine in linux. Trying to get it to work in windows.

Comment: "QGRaphcisScene" - That has two typos in it. Did you copy the error message by hand, or is it in the actual output? (The 'vtavle' above let's me assume you copied it by hand)

Comment: Is this about building Qt itself, or about building your own project against that Qt? If the latter, add your .pro file.

Comment: @Frank - I copied it by hand. Should have been more careful. The code I'm using compiles fine in ubuntu and when I build it in qt creator (by copying the header and sources files). I just installed qt from the link above. I'm trying to build a project I made in linux using qt in windows. The .pro file was made using qmake but I'll post it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethings weird.... You are trying to link `mingw32`, and at the same time you are using a `msvc2008` library path. They are separate and non-compatible compilers environments, so if you try linking objects compile from both you may have this error. What compiler are you using?? Are you using QtCreator? The compiler must be the same as the one which is used to compile the Qt libraries...

Comment: Nyobe. I just installed qt using the link I provided so I didn't build it myself. I'll reinstall it and try building it with mingw. I think this might be the correct line of thinking here.